# Can I use jquery children() to select children of a child element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, children

I'm trying to write a selector that has to cover both `ul`, `table` and `select` and selects `li`, `tr` and `options` in a single selector.

Since I cannot rule out a list being defined inside a table cell for example, I'm trying like this:

```
// el can either be a list, table, select
var items = el.children("li, option, tbody tr, tbody th");
```

But it looks like I cannot access table rows by selecting:

```
var items = "table".children("tbody tr");
```

**Question:**
Is there a way to use the `children()` method and also select "children of a child"? If not, is there a better way using jQuery?

Thanks!

**EDIT**:
I'm looking for a short way to do this:

```
if (el.get(0).tagName === "TABLE") {
   items = el.find("tbody tr");
} else if ( el.get(0).tagName === "UL") {
   items = el.children();
} else if ( el.get(0).tagName === "SELECT") {
   items = el.children();
}
```

Would be nice to do this in a one-liner, but I would need to have a way to access `tbody tr` in my `children()` call.

**Answer**:
This is my final selector:

```
items = el.find("> li, > option, tbody tr, tbody th, ui-controlgroup-controls ui-btn");
```

which so far gives me the correct elements, so when `el` is

```
table > returns: tr, tr, tr, tr
list > returns: li, li, li
select > returns: option, option, option
controlgroup > returns a.ui-btn, a.ui-btn, div.ui-btn
```

Thanks @adeneo!

Comment: Are you saying you want to be able to drill down to the deepest lis, trs, or options in a select, table, or list or that you just want to find them at any level as long as the context parent is one of the base three el var elements?

Comment: nope. I don't need the deepest. See my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you only want direct children, but if it is a table, you want all the `TR`'s. You can use the direct children selector `>` and `find()`, which would match only `LI` and `OPTION` elements that are direct children of `el` :

```
var items = el.find(' > li, > option, tbody tr, tbody th');
```

To avoid nested TR's you can even do :

```
var items = el.find(' > li, > option, > tbody > tr, > tbody > th');
```

Answer (score 1):

So you only want the very first descendants to much from el that are either TRs, LIs, or OPTIONs I'm now assuming. I'm not sure where browser variation stands on the tablebody thing so I would probably play it safe with this:

```
$('> li, > option, > tr, > tbody > tr', el);
```

Comment: this gives me all table cells :-)

Comment: That's what I would expect. I thought you wanted the children of all of your lis, options, and trs found in tables, lists, and selects. If you want the lis options and trs, just lose .children(). Or do you mean TDs only when you know there are things in options and lis that you want?

Comment: I have either a `ul`, `table` or `select` and what to select their `li`, `tr` and `options`. Problem is `tbody` vs `tr` being children of the table. I could use `find()` but I cannot know what is inside `li` or `tr` so if there is a nested list with list items for example, I don*t want to have the nested `li` end up inside my `find(li)`.

Comment: Ah... okay. so the first descendants to match only.

Comment: FYI, el in the second arg is essentially shorthand for find.

Answer (score 0):

You should checkout filter()
el.filter("tbody")

Comment: I know I could `filter()` but that would kick out `li` and `option`, too.